# Non-final variables and thread safety in JCIP

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

In [JCIP](http://jcip.net/) we have a piece of code which looks like this:

<sub>Listing 4.2:</sub>

```
@ThreadSafe
public class PersonSet {
    @GuardedBy("this")
    private final Set<Person> mySet = new HashSet<Person>(); // line 3

    public synchronized void addPerson(Person p) {
        mySet.add(p);
    }

    public synchronized boolean containsPerson(Person p) {
        return mySet.contains(p);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if we change the third line to this:

```
   private Set<Person> mySet = new HashSet<Person>(); // line 3, removes final
```

Is it true to say that the class is no longer thread-safe because the non-final variable `mySet` could have been null, even after the constructor exits and a reference to the PersonSet instance is published?

For example, is it true to say that a calling code like this may fail, or am I misunderstanding somthing? :

```
PersonSet p = new PersonSet();
SendToThreadB(p);
```

What if I have a restriction that does not allow the field to be marked "final" (like I may have to swap it with a new instance), what solutions are there to ensure that the class is still thread-safe without using `final` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `final`, instances become unsafe when used after *unsafe publication*. That is, if another thread gets access to the object without going through `synchronized`/`volatile` to produce an appropriate *happens-before* relationship then it may see a partially initialised object. In this case it would probably fail in a relatively safe way giving a `NullPointerException` on dereferencing the `mySet` field. In theory, another thread could see the reference to the `HashSet`, but some or all of the fields of that object may not have been set.

Comment: Heys  I was wondering is it true that without the `final`, after the constructor of `PersonSet` exits, the number of `HashSet<Person>` instances in the program may still have been zero? (assuming my program never calls the functions `addPerson` or `containsPerson`)

Comment: @Pacerier The `HashSet` would still be constructed, it's just that another thread may not see the reference to it.

Comment: heys sry I've got two quick questions, 1) is it true that the `HashSet` is **guaranteed** to be constructed when the constructor of PersonSet returns? (in other words it isn't delayed to some other time?) 2) what's the point of the `final` in the code above since `addPerson` and `containsPerson` are already synchronized?

Comment: @Pacerier What do you mean by after? From the thread that constructed `PersonSet`, yes the `HashSet` has been fully constructed before the return. But in the presence of *unsafe publication* (no appropriate *happens-before* relationship) another thread may see a different ordering. `final` has additional semantics that ensure even with unsafe publication, **so long as the `PersonSet` constructor has finished before publication,** that the field and the objects pointed at by it (and only by it) are all available.

Comment: heys I've detailed the question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6509/4394. Please take a look, thanks in advance =D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to change the field value, make the field `volatile` if you want changes to the field to be visible to other threads without having to use other *happens-before* mechanisms. (Reading and writing a `volatile` field are *happens-before* events.)

Of course, if you always use other *happens-before* systems (e.g., `synchronized`, mutex locks, `BlockingQueue`, `Exchanger`, setting the field value before creating the thread you're sending it to, etc.), then `volatile` isn't necessary. But that is more fragile, because if you later change code such that no *happens-before* happens any more, then you've created a bug.

Comment: Do you mean to say that it is true that removing the "final" keyword would spoil the thread-safety of the code shown above?

Comment: Not as shown above, but if you change the field later on, any other threads may not see the new value. (Changes in one thread are not guaranteed to be visible to other threads unless there's a _happens-before_ event that happens in between the change and the retrieval. `volatile` is one way to provide this.)

Comment: Does the `final` guarantees that the instance of the `HashSet<Person>` is created when the constructor of `PersonSet` exits?

Comment: Yes, but, IIRC, even without the `final`, that guarantee still holds. (Tom Hawtin will probably correct me.)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `final`, the class is still thread-safe because of the `synchronized` modifier on the methods.  They will provide the *happens-before* relationship that guarantees that everyone will see the same value for the `mySet` reference.

The point about the `final` is that it makes this variant thread-safe with respect to the class ifself.

```
public class PersonSet {
    private final Set<Person> mySet = new HashSet<Person>();

    public Set<Person> getSet() {
        return mySet;
    }
}
```

Note that there is no `synchronized` modifier on the getter.

(Of course, any code that gets hold of the `HashSet` object needs to synchronize their operations on the object ... somehow ... which means that this is NOT an example of good design.)

Comment: Ic. Btw just to confirm do you mean that without `final`, it's true that `mySet` may be `null` after the constructor block exits? whereas with `final`,  `mySet` may **never** be `null` after the constructor block exits?

Comment: The `mySet` variable will never be seen as `null` if the methods that allow you to see it are `synchronized`.  Even if you remove the `final`.

Comment: however is it true that the number of `HashSets` in the program may be zero even after I have created an instance of `PersonSet` and constructor has exited (,but I have not called any of the synchronized methods) ? whereas if I put in the final, the number of HashSets is guaranteed to be 1 after the constructor exits?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right -- you need the `final` keyword, and without it, another thread could see mySet as `null`.

Constructors have no memory barriers or synchronization, other than for `final` fields. So even though the various modifications to the HashSet are all guarded by the same monitor (the one that belongs to `this`), the assignment of that object's reference to the mySet field is not guarded.